# How to control Div from CSS for Print View

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have table which contains few colomns and 1000 rows. When I am print the page it breaks rows in page and show remaining on other page. I want it should display the complete record in .

This is a sample code. I have inserted the one row but if we put 1000 rows then it is creating the problem

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
@media screen
{
.divTable
{
    border:1px solid;
    display:  table;
    width:98%;
    border-spacing:0px;/*cellspacing:poor IE support for  this*/
    /* border-collapse:separate;*/
}
.divRow
{
   display:table-row;
   width:auto;
}
.divCell
{
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
    float:left;/*fix for  buggy browsers*/
    display:table-column;
}
}
@media print
{
  @page
  {
   size: 8.5in 11.5in;
   size: potraite;
  }
  .divTable
  {
    page-break-after:auto;  
    border:1px solid;
    display:  table;
    width:99%;
    border-spacing:0px;/*cellspacing:poor IE support for  this*/
    /* border-collapse:separate;*/
  }
  .divRow
  {
    display:table-row;
    width:auto;
  }
  .divCell
  {
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
    float:left;
    display:table-column;
  }
}
</style>
</head>

<body style="margin:0 0 0 0">
<div class="divTable">
 <div class="headRow">
  <div class="divCell" style="width:10%">
    SNo
  </div>
  <div class="divCell" style="width:10%">
    RNo
  </div>
  <div class="divCell" style="width:10%">
    Full Name
  </div>
  <div class="divCell" style="width:10%">
    Father Name
  </div>
  <div class="divCell" style="width:20%">
    Address
  </div>
  <div class="divCell" style="width:10%">
    Class
  </div>
  <div class="divCell" style="width:10%">
    Section
  </div>
  <div class="divCell" style="width:10%">
    Teacher Name
  </div>
  <div class="divCell" style="width:10%">
   Attendence%
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="divTable">
 <div class="headRow">
  <div class="divCell" style="width:10%">
   1
  </div>
  <div class="divCell" style="width:10%">
    RNo2013-0001
  </div>
  <div class="divCell" style="width:10%">
    Abc
  </div>
  <div class="divCell" style="width:10%">
    Xyz
  </div>
  <div class="divCell" style="width:20%">
    Address
  </div>
  <div class="divCell" style="width:10%">
    Class
  </div>
  <div class="divCell" style="width:10%">
    Section
  </div>
  <div class="divCell" style="width:10%">
    Teacher Name
  </div>
  <div class="divCell" style="width:10%">
   90%
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Kindly tell me the solution how to manage it with css. I have to do only with css

Answer (score 0):

It seems logical that there is only so many space on one page.
you could try this, at least, if you wish to hide your unused cells.:
`empty-cells:hide;`

```
  .divTable
  {
    page-break-after:auto;  
    border:1px solid;
    display:  table;
    width:99%;
    border-spacing:0px;/*cellspacing:poor IE support for  this*/
    empty-cells:hide;
  }
```

Also, why are you using divs instead of the default HTML 5 table layout?

Comment: Thank for the reply. Its working but not properly. In large data when going for 5-10 pages its missing it. means 1st line on page page and 2nd line on other page

Comment: is there any way to show the code in action with large amounts of data then? Because with just this, i'm affraid I don't know the solution.

Comment: hmmmmm just take a for loop and print div for 1000 times and then see in the print view...

Comment: Well if there is any other way to do page break when we dont know how much data is there.